# Can Java Scene Builder integrate into Eclipse like it does in NetBeans?

Tags: eclipse, javafx-2, scenebuilder

I was just wondering since I am used to programming in My/Eclipse...
Is it possible for javafx scene builder to intergrade into eclipse like it does in netbeans: in netbeans you can double click on a "Front end" file/component and java fx scene builder opens up.

I am not used to Net Beans and I know it will not make a huge difference if I have to use Netbeans. Only wondered if that is possible. I googled this and dont seem to find the correct information.... Or I might be searching for the wrong thing.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the [efxclipse](http://www.efxclipse.org/) plugin as stated by @user714965 when you right click a FXML file, the second option from the context menu is "Open with Scene Builder". But, if you want to make it the standard procedure on double click, you can simply go to:

Preferences -> Editors -> File association -> look for .fxml and select it -> Click the second add button on "Associated Editors" -> Open with external program -> Select scene builder.

This should make the double-click action to open scene builder with your file loaded.

I hope it helped. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I think [efxclipse](http://www.efxclipse.org/) is what you are looking for. But I haven't used it yet.

Comment: thx, from what I can see is that it only allows you to code and use Ctrl+Space features. It doesn't allow you to switch between eclipse and javafx scene builder.